# Integrated graphics not giving out signals through any port

Tags: display, external-display, displayport, integrated-graphics, display-adapter

I have been trying to re-enable my integrated graphics card as my dedicated graphics has no HDMI port but when I connect HDMI or VGA to my integrated graphics port there is no display. I searched the Internet about how to re-enable integrated graphics and all I found was to enable IGPU in BIOS settings but there is no IGPU setting in my BIOS menu. Motherboard Name Gigabyte GAH57M-USB3. So can someone please help me to re-enable my integrated graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Advanced BIOS Features`, there are `Init Display First` and `Onboard VGA` (and also `On-Chip Frame Buffer Size`).

According to the [manual](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3307#manual) (scroll down; not the Installation Guidebook), there are only two options for `Onboard VGA`: `Enable If No Ext PEG` and `Always Enable`. So unless you want to use the iGPU while keeping the PEG (PCI Express Graphics) installed, either of them should work.

It should be of similar case for `Init Display First`: unless you've got a display card installed one of the PCI(e) slots, it should not matter which option you picked for this parameter.

So if you do wanna keep the PEG installed but to use the iGPU (as the primary graphics), you should choose `Always Enable` for `Onboard VGA`, and `Onboard` for `Init Display First`.

Comment: I dont have any onboard vga option on my bios settings

Comment: @KartikPillai well talk to Gigabyte then. I am not responsible for the difference in the BIOS and the manual they manufactured/released.

Comment: @KartikPillai Check if you have the latest BIOS. [Gigabyte](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3307#bios) doesn't mention that any update adds such an option, yet I would update the old BIOS in a hope it would, especially if the latest manual mentions the option. There is usually some risk involved with that process. Read about it an decide for yourself.

Comment: To be honest, I am not very persuaded that it really lacks the option without a picture capturing his BIOS screen showing the `Advanced BIOS Features` page.

Comment: @TomYan Do you want a screen shot of my advanced options bios menu??

Comment: @KartikPillai well it's up to you. the thing is even if you're not missing anything, the only you can do is still talking to gigabyte.